# Zend query sort by multiplication of columns

Tags: database, zend-framework

I am trying to query some rows from a MySQL database with Zend Framework 1. I need all columns, but want to sort them by a multiplication of columns:

```
$select = $this
            ->select()
            ->where('start_date < ' . $currentTime)
            ->where('end_date >' . $currentTime)
            ->order('columnA * columnB DESC');
```

This obviously isn't working.

With the Zend documentation, I'm getting to this:

```
$select = $this->select()
         ->from(array('p' => 'products'),
                array('product_id',
                      'order_column' =>
                          new Zend_Db_Expr('columnA * columnB'))
                )
         ->order('order_column DESC);
```

However, this only returns the product_id and new order_column, but I need all columns.

How to get there? How to return all columns of the selected rows, ordered by columnA * columnB?

Answer (score 0):

Too quick. I found the solution by trying:

```
$select = $this
    ->select()
    ->where('start_date < ' . $currentTime)
    ->where('end_date >' . $currentTime)
    ->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('columnA * columnB DESC'));
```

This gives the desired result.